# Desktop speakers with headphone port and separate volume controls

Tags: audio, speakers, headphones

I currently use the excellent [Logitech X-230](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/speakers_audio/home_pc_speakers/devices/208&cl=AU,EN) desktop speaker/subwoofer set, which I love for the volume dial on the front which gives me a nice, quick, tactile control of my sound without requiring a remote or keyboard buttons or some awkward software slider.  Additionally, there's a very convenient headphone jack right next to the volume dial but the volume dial only controls the speakers, leaving the headphones at full volume.

The goal is to be able to adjust the sound in my headphones without having to fumble around and find an inline headphone volume control (and my current favorite pair doesn't even have one).

Is anyone aware of a desktop speaker set that has convenient volume controls for both levels?

Comment: IIRC, the Logitech X-230 (I happen to own a set myself) actually departed from the norm in the volume control department.  Virtually every other PC speaker set I've run into had the headphone volume controlled via the speaker's volume knob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Creative Inspire T3100](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.creative.com%2Fproducts%2Fproduct.asp%3Fcategory%3D4%26subcategory%3D27%26product%3D15773&ei=26x2SqrJCqbqnAONh-X_Cw&rct=j&q=Creative+Inspire+T3100&usg=AFQjCNGRR92_4sqDAzq3q3C3zzbNqWAfsw&sig2=aYHvnAa28bixI3qKNV4ELg) desktop speaker/subwoofer set.
They have a volume dial at the front and a headphone jack left, next to the volume dial.
The volume dial also controls the headphones.

There is also the Inspire M2600 set which is very similar, but has a remote control.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to [Logitech Z2300](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/speakers_audio/home_pc_speakers/devices/231&cl=CA,EN), which I've been using for the last 5 years, they have that function and is probably a very good upgrade sound-wise for your current speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I've owned the [Creative T20 speakers](http://au.creative.com/products/product.asp?category=4&subcategory=789&product=14299&listby=usage) for the last year and have been very happy with them.

On the front of one speaker it has a volume control (controls speakers & headphones), Bass and Treble controls, headphone out, line in (great for listening to an MP3 player through speakers).

There's no subwoofer, but that just means that for the price you get better quality speakers.  The frequency range is quite good also.